# A little Silvester puzzle

Tags: problems

A regular game has been played where White still has all 16 pieces. White promoted only a single pawn, and not to queen. In the final position all 16 pieces of White have (at least) one mating move. Yes, also the king. Find the position. ("The"=it is *mostly* determined, allowing for variations)

Yes, fitting for Silvester there is a little gag hidden, but it is entirely conforming to FIDE rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a solution that comes with a promoted bishop. All 16 white pieces have at least one mating move, the star among them being 0-0-0#.

A problemists problem with this is, as was pointed out by OP, that it's an *impossible position* due to black's double pawns.

```
[fen "1nbBbb2/PP1P1PP1/1BpkBQ2/2p1p1N1/1P3P2/2N4R/8/R3K3 w Q - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Essentially the same position (as I said, some leeway) as I intended. I merely saved two pawns, but then, I'm a chess composer pro :-) See here: https://www.hamburger-schachverband.de/berichte/2022/silvester22.bmp

Comment: I am Patz, you are Gurke, the Pc6 protects against the R mate :P

Comment: Told the webmaster to overwrite it with your correct version :-)

Comment: <sad horn>As an expert spotted, how did Black get the double pawn?</sad horn> Rats.

Comment: "J'adoube!" was said, I guess. Edited.